# Querying in Custom Visualization app in splunk

Tags: splunk, flowchart

I am querying splunk with the help of a query that I made to search the splunk database.

Now this query is giving me a lot of fields as the result. But I want only selected fields in the output. How to do that?

I am using 'Custom Visualization' app in splunk. I want my splunk query to be used in Custom Visualization so that a flowchart is produced. How to achieve this thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can do to limit the number of fields. It all depends on your query (which you forgot to attach, so we could help better).

Without seeing your query, these are what I would suggest:

1. [fields](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/fields)
2. [table](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/6.2.5/SearchReference/table)

For your second question, you will need to create a dashboard, and follow the tutorial section of the Custom Visualization app. Which involves creating your own dashboard, and importing the appropriate javascript/css files, and use an html section of the dashboard with the right options. Without seeing what you have attempted with this, it would be hard to help.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Figured it out with fields and table hint.

Comment: Be sure to up vote the answer if I helped, and accept the answer if it answered your questions.